# Bitcoin Core client upgrade from V0.7 2-beta to latest 0.15.X (Oct2017) - ‘wallet.dat’?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I need to apply an upgrade to my Bitcoin Core client From V0.7 2-beta to latest.

I've got some advice that I need to make that upgrade a 2 step process 
(i) V0.7 2-beta' TO Bitcoin Core 0.14.2 
(ii) Bitcoin Core 0.14.2 to Bitcoin Core 0.15.X

My questions is regarding my ‘wallet.dat’ file in this 2 step process.

Does the wallet.Dat file need to be put back in AFTER phase (i) and resynched ? 
OR 
Can I put the wallet.Dat file back in for the first time only after phase (ii) and synch ?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to touch the wallet file (but back it up), the format hasn’t changed and is safe to upgrade on top of.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to "put back" anything or touch any files (including the wallet.dat) in the Bitcoin Core data directory.

The upgrade form 0.7.2 to 0.14.2 is to upgrade the chainstate databases which are completely separate from and unrelated to your wallet. Since the chainstate database format changed again for 0.15, the upgrade from 0.14.2 to 0.15 will upgrade the database format again. There is no direct upgrade from 0.7.2 to 0.15 as 0.15+ does not have code to migrate from the older database format.